# Plot seaborn boxplot for multiple columns and compare with a standard scale

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I am a newbie in data analysis. I wish to know how to boxplot multiple columns (x-axis = Points, Score, Weigh) in a single graph and make the y-axis as a standardized scale for comparison. I have tried and couldn't understand the code (Python+Pandas+Seaborn) for this. Help me out guys. The dataset for the same is as follows:

|  | Cars | Points | Score | Weigh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mazda RX4 | 3.90 | 2.620 | 16.46 |
| 1 | Mazda RX4 Wag | 3.90 | 2.875 | 17.02 |
| 2 | Datsun 710 | 3.85 | 2.320 | 18.61 |
| 3 | Hornet 4 Drive | 3.08 | 3.215 | 19.44 |
| 4 | Hornet Sportabout | 3.15 | 3.440 | 17.02 |
| 5 | Valiant | 2.76 | 3.460 | 20.22 |
| 6 | Duster 360 | 3.21 | 3.570 | 15.84 |
| 7 | Merc 240D | 3.69 | 3.190 | 20.00 |
| 8 | Merc 230 | 3.92 | 3.150 | 22.90 |
| 9 | Merc 280 | 3.92 | 3.440 | 18.30 |
| 10 | Merc 280C | 3.92 | 3.440 | 18.90 |
| 11 | Merc 450SE | 3.07 | 4.070 | 17.40 |
| 12 | Merc 450SL | 3.07 | 3.730 | 17.60 |
| 13 | Merc 450SLC | 3.07 | 3.780 | 18.00 |
| 14 | Cadillac Fleetwood | 2.93 | 5.250 | 17.98 |
| 15 | Lincoln Continental | 3.00 | 5.424 | 17.82 |
| 16 | Chrysler Imperial | 3.23 | 5.345 | 17.42 |
| 17 | Fiat 128 | 4.08 | 2.200 | 19.47 |
| 18 | Honda Civic | 4.93 | 1.615 | 18.52 |
| 19 | Toyota Corolla | 4.22 | 1.835 | 19.90 |
| 20 | Toyota Corona | 3.70 | 2.465 | 20.01 |
| 21 | Dodge Challenger | 2.76 | 3.520 | 16.87 |
| 22 | AMC Javelin | 3.15 | 3.435 | 17.30 |
| 23 | Camaro Z28 | 3.73 | 3.840 | 15.41 |
| 24 | Pontiac Firebird | 3.08 | 3.845 | 17.05 |
| 25 | Fiat X1-9 | 4.08 | 1.935 | 18.90 |
| 26 | Porsche 914-2 | 4.43 | 2.140 | 16.70 |
| 27 | Lotus Europa | 3.77 | 1.513 | 16.90 |
| 28 | Ford Pantera L | 4.22 | 3.170 | 14.50 |
| 29 | Ferrari Dino | 3.62 | 2.770 | 15.50 |
| 30 | Maserati Bora | 3.54 | 3.570 | 14.60 |
| 31 | Volvo 142E | 4.11 | 2.780 | 18.60 |

My output should look something like:
[Output Boxplot Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCdmr.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("test_data.txt")
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8,4)
data.boxplot(column=['Points', 'Score', 'Weigh'], grid='true', color='blue',fontsize=10, rot=30)
```

[image: example_1.png]

And with seaborn:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv("test_data.txt")
ax = sns.boxplot(data=data, palette="Set2")
```

[image: example_2.png]

Comment: Yes this looks good. Any idea on how to do this via seaborn?

Answer (score 0):

boxplot = df.boxplot(column=['Points', 'Score', 'Weight'])

might work here